# Enter Database PHP connection with userform

Tags: php, authentication, post, mysqli

I'm trying to enter a username into a text field and click submit then this should connect me to my database.
A) What is wrong with the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 


<?php

// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if (empty($_POST["login"]))
    {
        $nameErr = "login is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $login = test_input($_POST["login"]);

        // check if login only contains letters and whitespace
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$login))
       {
           $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
       }
    }
}

function test_input($data)
{
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Edge User Login</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 

Login: <input type="text" name="name">
       <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       <br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php

    $mysqli_connection = new MySQLi('localhost', $login, 'secret', 'edgeserver');

    if ($mysqli_connection->connect_error)
    {
        echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;
    }

?>
```

B) I dont want the user to have to enter a username everytime they run a PHP command. Is there a way of using a master sheet that can be referred back to?

Comment: A) We would not know what would be wrong with the codes except for syntax errors if there any. You need to give us a brief explanation of what you are trying to do. B) What do you mean by "I dont want the user to have to enter a username everytime they run a PHP command"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A.) You probably don't want your users to connect to MySql through your server

These should be YOUR login details from MySql, typically you create a user in MySql (maybe phpmyadmin?) and fill the details in here:

```
$mysqli_connection = new MySQLi('localhost', $login, 'secret', 'edgeserver');
```

Then you would select from a table you create that holds your users.

B.) You can store user-names in sessions, but that's getting complicated, and I’d recommend you get it working where you just login first.

Possibly [this](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html) ( I just googled it ) might help you.

Comment: Great link. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: np. don't forget to mark my answer as correct if it solved the problem for you.